# How to open a PDF document by clicking a button?

Tags: java, swing, pdf

I develop an employee payroll management system using Java and Netbeans. I want to open a .pdf file when I click the open button.

But I want to select that file when I click the open button.

How can I do that?

I want to use `JFileChooser`.

So how can I open the PDF file using `JFileChooser`?

This is the code of Open button but this is not complete - it does not open the PDF.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose for opening the file? Do you want to preview it in your program or launching external application to do something?

Comment: I want to preview a pdf file in my program..

Comment: But one thought: I hope this project is just for learning; and you are not really working on such a system to be used in the real world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parts in there:

- Use the file chooser to select a file (you already got that)
- Then use that file name with either some Java component that is able to open/present the PDF file; or use javas [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to start a new external process that uses some tool like Adobe Reader to open that file.

More ideas could be found [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-java/) for example.

Comment: Can u tell me the coding for second part??

Comment: *"Can u tell me the coding for second part? "* For part 2 rather than use `ProcessBuilder`, I'd recommend **`Desktop.getDesktop().open(File)`**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(path));` like this :

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     openFile();
}
```

Method to use `JFileChooser` and open your pdf file :

```
private void openFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {


    FileFilter fJavaFilter = new FileFilter();
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setDialogTitle("Open your file");
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
    fc.setFileFilter(fJavaFilter);

    int result = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        //cancel action
    } else if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        //open file using 
        File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

        File myFile = new File(path);
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

We use `FileFilter` to filter only our extension we need if you don't want to use any filter you can comment this two lines like this :

```
    //FileFilter fJavaFilter = new FileFilter();
    //....
    //fc.setFileFilter(fJavaFilter);
```

If you want to use Filter you can add this class to your project or you can use it in the same class :

```
class FileFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        //your filter here
        return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")
                || f.isDirectory();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Select file (*.pdf)";
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows an error on first line.. on this word FileFilter();

Comment: @GhostCat what did you mean it is `java.awt.Desktop` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html